# My PHP script can't connect to an IRC server

Tags: php, sockets, irc, fsockopen

I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. I am using `$sock = fsockopen("irc.esper.net", 6667)` to try to connect to the server. I've also tried using port 5555 and using the server name aperture.esper.net. All of which fail with either a timeout or network not reachable error (checked the logs). The whole code is here:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$sock = fsockopen("irc.ipv6.esper.net", 6667);

echo("Joined");

if (!$sock) {
    exit(1);
}

fputs($sock, "USER kodas2_ :kodas2_");
fputs($sock, "NICK h1a2r\r\n");
fputs($sock, "JOIN #minecraft\r\n");

while (true) {

}
?>
```

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sock =@ fsockopen("irc.esper.net", 6667, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if ($sock) {
    printf("No error, go on.");
}
```

Says: `No error, go on.`

```
$sock =@ fsockopen("irc.ipv6.esper.net", 6667, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$sock) {
    printf("errno: %s, errstr: %s", $errno, $errstr);
}
```

Says: `errno: 0, errstr: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.`

So, check your hosts first whether valid or not.

Comment: +1 **Always** use the built-in error functions/globals/return values.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to set your firewall to allow 6667 ports i expect.